# Method reference on map function, compilation error when the key is of type String

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors, hashmap, method-reference

**Context**:

I want to use the function `computeIfAbsent` on a `Map`. But, I get a compilation error when I use

- *method reference* and the key is a `String`.

I get no compilation error when I use

- *method reference* and the key is an `Integer`.
- *lambda* and the key is a `String`.

**Illustration**:

The following statements are *legal*:

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> map = new HashMap<>();
Integer key = Integer.valueOf(0);
Long value = Long.valueOf(2);
map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new).add(value); // No compilation error
```

The following statements are *illegal*:

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map = new HashMap<>();
String key = "myKey";
Long value = Long.valueOf(2);
map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new).add(value); // Compilation error: The type ArrayList does not define ArrayList(String) that is applicable here
```

The following statements are *legal*:

```
Map<String, List<Long>> map = new HashMap<>();
String key = "myKey";
Long value = Long.valueOf(2);
map.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value); // No compilation error
```

**Question**:
I don't get why a `String` as key is that special when combined with method reference. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `ArrayList::new` instead of `x -> new ArrayList<>()` it's equals to call `x -> new ArrayList<>(x)`.

Method `computeIfAbsent` requires lambda expression with one lambda parameter as second input argument, or a reference to method that consumes one argument of `String` type.

Your error

> Compilation error: The type ArrayList does not define ArrayList(String) that is applicable here

is talking: `you trying to call constructor with one String argument`. Because, as I told above, lambda `x -> someObject.method(x)` is equal to `someObject::method`. Or lambda `x -> new SomeClass(x)` is equal to `SomeClass::new`.

You can't use method (constructor) reference here, because here required method (constructor) that consumes one parameter, or a lambda expression. If there was lambda without any parameters, you will be able to call empty constructor.

Comment: Your answer gave me the hint that I needed: in ArrayList class there is only the following constructor:
ArrayList(), 
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c), 
ArrayList(int initialCapacity). Thx

Comment: @KeyMaker00 hmm.. I told that you use method references not as needed :) I have tried to explain what the error is. if the answer satisfies you, mark it as correct. GL :)